# Synchronize Git repo to another removing some (confidential) files

Tags: git

Git isn't able to manage permission/right on folders/files contrary to CVS like Subversion/Perforce. But I need that in my environment.

One good workaround for that is to create multiple repos, but it's not a great solution for my environment, and I try to find another solution with allow to keep a global main repo.

So, I think about having a main repo with all the files, even the one which will be restricted. And then duplicate/synchronize this repo to another repo that will be the same except that the restricted files/folder will be removed.

Of course, it means that this second repo will have different SHA1/history, but while it will be only used by developer with restricted access, it's not a problem. They won't send path to developer which have access to the main repo.

"git filter-branch" or BFG tool could removed files/folder, but here I will need to keep the both repo synchronized (for the not protected files).

So, is there a solution/tool to keep the both repo synchronized (in both direction) and remove the unwanted files in the second repos ?

Answer (score 0):

Git is not a deployment management tool. What language are you using? There's probably more appropriate tools available for your build chain that would solve this problem.

Comment: I don't want to deploy code. I want to replicate/synchronize a git repo but with one repo which have some folder/files removed. This is not a language depend question. It's related to a way to workaround permission/rights issues when using git (at the opposite of CVS which proposer folder user permission). The both repo will be acces in read/write by developers. The first repo by developer which have all the access, and the other by the developer which restricted access.